# How to execute a script from trusted shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am new to Linux. I have copied the `bash` program from `bin` to a thumb drive. I have renamed it to "ebash". Now I connect this thumb drive to other Linux machine. I have mounted this drive and navigated to the directory where I have placed ebash through terminal.

Now I run a script like this with root access.

```
# ebash script.sh
```

The output looks like

```
No command 'ebash' found, did you mean:
 Command 'bash' from package 'bash' (main)
 Command 'rbash' from package 'bash' (main)
ebash: command not found
```

I want to execute the script using ebash now.

The first line of the script I have written is

```
#!/mnt/mntpoint/Tools/ebash
```

Is this the write procedure to execute the script using a trusted shell?
If not please help me with the correct procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a script you've downloaded as a file, you'll want to `./ebash` instead of `ebash`. What this does is it executes from the current directory (`./`) the file named ebash.

Typing in `ebash` looks for that command to be installed in `/bin` or another place and would not look to execute files in external directories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. First line of the code i have written is "#!/mnt/evid-collector/Tools/ebash". Does this line effect my code.

Comment: Not in this case. Normally that first line is to tell what program is used to run a script, but you're already using your `ebash` to run it.